# How to start a background thread that doesn't block the main thread in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, blocking, runnable

I have the following Java code:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new Thread(new MyRunnable()).run();
    showGUI();
}
```

My problem is that starting `MyRunnable` blocks the main thread, causing `showGUI` to not be called until it finishes running. What I'd *like* the program to do is spawn `MyRunnable` and allow it to run independently in the background, enabling the main thread to forget about it and go ahead and do what it wants (like call `showGUI`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`run` executes on the main thread. `start` will create a new thread execution and execute it's run method on that thread.

Answer (score 12):

You should call method `start()` on thread, not `run()`.